# Error while trying to load site

Tags: magento2, error, store-view, multi-language

I wanted to add multilanguage support to a website I am creating, thus I followed a guide to do so.
After completing the steps, I tried to refresh the site and got the following error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 833

Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 834

Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 835

Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 836

Internal error: xmlSchemaXPathProcessHistory, The state object to be removed is not the first in the list.
Line: 831

Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateChildElem, calling xmlRegExecPushString2().
Line: 840

Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateElem, calling xmlSchemaStreamValidateChildElement().
Line: 840

Internal error: xmlSchemaDocWalk, calling xmlSchemaValidateElem().
Line: 840


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 833

Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 834

Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 835

Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 836

Internal error: xmlSchemaXPathProcessHistory, The state object to be removed is not the first in the list.
Line: 831

Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateChildElem, calling xmlRegExecPushString2().
Line: 840

Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateElem, calling xmlSchemaStreamValidateChildElement().
Line: 840

Internal error: xmlSchemaDocWalk, calling xmlSchemaValidateElem().
Line: 840
```

I also get the following:

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Config\DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php:524]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php:500]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor.php:149]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:271]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:896]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:293]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor\magento\module-cms\Helper\Page.php:218]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor\magento\module-cms\Controller\Index\Index.php:74]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php:51]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php:23]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php:111]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#24 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#25 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#26 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php:32]
#27 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:186]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:118]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#32 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#34 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php:23]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:116]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:23]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:263]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:29]
```

I tried deleting the Store View, Re-indexing the Indexes and clearing the Cache but nothing seems to be working.

The guide I followed: https://magefan.com/blog/configure-magento-2-multi-language-store

Any help will be much appreciated!

Have a great day and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below commands-

```
rm -rf generated/* var/cache/*
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```